# Add Watch Expression in Eclipse using keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I need help adding a keyboard shortcut for adding a watch expression in Eclipse.  I can add a watch by right-clicking in the "Expressions View", but having go back and forth between the keyboard and mouse cuts down on efficiency.

Can anyone offer me any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Preferences (on Mac its Eclipse > PReferences.. not sure what heading prefs is under on win/*nix) and expand the "General" section and select "Keys" you will then get a pane with a search dialog. Type in "watch" and set it up appropriately.

Comment: I was unable to get the "Watch" command to do anything when activated via hot key. Is there a trick to this?

Comment: @Jonathan: The one you used might not actually be the one youre looking for... so sometimes it takes some trial error... I know i did thes when i was trying to set a hot key for external commands.

Comment: Multiple Watch commands? The description for the hotkey says "Add Watch Expression." Thinking it's just plain ol' 'broked'.

Comment: I can't believe it, that still there is no default shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

same way you can use for windows. it works.

Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work if i first:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys (type filter text: watch). 
Set the Binding to a free Shortcut of your choice (i've choosen Shift+W).
```

**Select 'Debugging' in the below 'When:' dropbox. It now works as soon as my debugger is running (but it wont work if youre currently not debugging.**

Hope that helps to work with that crippled "something like an IDE" eclipse thing i currently have to "work" with as well ...